# How to count how many mapped cards in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an react app that has search bar, cards with information, filters, the problem is that when I search it re mapped the cards depend on the value, but there is times that there is no card mapped, so I want to count the cards mapped so I set default mapped cards if the there is mapped cards (0). (To summarize I don't want the page to be empty), If there is better idea I would appreciate it.

The code

```
//Function to create the cards with thier proipte values
function CreateCards(doc) {
    return(
        <SimpleCard
        key={doc.id}
        theCardId={doc.id}
        cardType={doc.approvetool}
        cardNum={doc.num}
        cardName={doc.name}
        cardDate={doc.date}
        // cardCategory={NCARMap.cardCategory}
        // cardSource={NCARMap.cardSource}
        cardDesc={doc.summary}
        cardURL={doc.image}
        />
    );

}

//create the class
export default class OfficialDocument extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      NCARMap: [],
      NCARMapAS: [],
      search_query:"",
      count: 0,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //Get NCARMap data, NCARMapAS used for filtring and sorting the cards
      axios.get('http://localhost:9200/ncar_index/ncar/_search')
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp)
            this.setState({
              NCARMap: resp.data.hits.hits,
              NCARMapAS:resp.data.hits.hits,
        })
        console.log(this.state.NCARMap)
    })
}
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({   
    search_query: event.target.value,
  })
  if(this.state.count > 0){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:9200/ncar_index/ncar/_search?q=${this.state.search_query}`)
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp)
        console.log("here" +this.state.search_query)
        this.setState({
          NCARMap: resp.data.hits.hits,
    })
    console.log(this.state.NCARMap)
    console.log("here" +this.state.search_query)
})
}else{
  this.setState({   
    search_query:"",
  })
}
  }

  

    render(){

      

        return(
          //HTML FILE Converted to React
            <div>
  <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>منشآت</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  {/*============= ScrollToTop Section Starts Here =============*/}
  <div className="overlayer" id="overlayer">
    <div className="loader">
      <div className="loader-inner" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#0" className="scrollToTop"><i className="fas fa-angle-up" /></a>
  <div className="overlay" />
  {/*============= ScrollToTop Section Ends Here =============*/}
  {/*============= Header Section Starts Here =============*/}
  <header className="header-section">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="header-wrapper">
        <div className="logo-area">
          <div className="logo">
            <a href="/">
              <img src="/images/logo/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="support headFont">
            <a href="/">الصفحة الرئيسية</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul className="menu headFont">
          <li>
            {/*Here we need to change the herf link*/}
            <a href="/OfficialDocument">الوثائق و المحفوظات</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/WasPage">الأخبار</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            {/*Here we need to change the herf link*/}
            <a href="/TweetsPage">التغريدات</a>
          </li>
          {/*Here we need to change the herf link*/}
          {/* I want to know the diffrence between the two below */}
          <li className="d-md-none text-center">
            <a href="#0" className="m-0 header-button">تسجيل دخول</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="header-bar d-lg-none">
          <span style={{backgroundColor: '#00A7CF'}} />
          <span style={{backgroundColor: '#00A7CF'}} />
          <span style={{backgroundColor: '#00A7CF'}} />
        </div>
        {/* <div class="header-right"> */}
        {/*Here we need to change the herf link*/}
        {/* <a href="#0" class="header-button d-none d-md-inline-block">تسجيل دخول</a>
          </div> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  {/*============= Header Section Ends Here =============*/}
  {/*============= Banner Section Starts Here =============*/}
  <section className="banner-2 bg_img" data-background="/images/banner/background3.png">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="banner-content-2">
        <h1 className="title cl-white">مرحباً بك في قسم الوثائق والمحفوظات</h1>
        <p className=" cl-white">يحتوي هذا القسم على الوثائق والمحفوظات المعتمدة من المركز الوطني للوثائق والمحفوظات</p>
        <form className="search-form round">
          <input type="text" style={{textAlign: 'right', color: 'black'}} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="... ابحث هنا" />
          <button type="submit"><i className="flaticon-search" /> <span className="d-none d-sm-inline-block">ابحث</span></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  {/*============= Banner Section Ends Here =============*/}
  {/*============= How Search Section Starts Here =============*/}
  <div className="how-search-section padding-bottom mt--93">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mb-30-none justify-content-center">
      <div className="filter-rtl">
           {/*begin::Body*/}
<div className="card-body filters">
  {/*begin::Form*/}
  <form>
    {/*begin::Categories*/}
    <div className="form-group mb-11">
      <label className="font-size-h3 font-weight-bolder text-dark mb-7">التنصيفات</label>
      {/* start dropdown menue */}
      <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        أداة الاعتماد
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">أمر ملكي</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">مرسوم ملكي</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">قرار مجلس الوزراء</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">أمر سامي</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">قرار وزاري</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">قرار مجالس وهيئات</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">قرار إداري</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">توجيه سامي</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        فئة الوثيقة
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">الاتفاقيات و المعادات الدولية العامة</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">الاتفاقيات الدولية الثنائية</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">الاتفاقيات الدولية متعددة الأطراف</a>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    {/* end dropdown menue */}
    {/* Start: : DateRangePickerComponent */}
        <DateRangePickerComponent></DateRangePickerComponent>
    {/* End: : DateRangePickerComponent */}
    {/*end::Categories*/}
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary font-weight-bolder mr-2 px-8">إعادة ضبط</button>
    <button type="reset" className="btn-submit btn btn-clear font-weight-bolder text-muted px-8">بحث</button>
  </form>
  {/*end::Form*/}
</div>
{/*end::Body*/}
</div>
      <div className="general-card"> 
        {this.state.NCARMap.map((v, count)=> CreateCards(v._source), this.state.count+=1)}
        {console.log(this.state.NCARMap)}
        {console.log(this.state.count)}
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {/*============= How Search Section Ends Here =============*/}
  {/*============= Footer Section Starts Here =============*/}
  <footer className="footer-section pt-70-145">
    <div className="dot-slider bg_img" />
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mb--50 justify-content-between">
        <div className="col-sm-8 col-lg-4">
          <div className="footer-widget widget-about">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="footer-bottom cl-white">
      <p>جميع الحقوق محفوظة © 2021</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  {/*============= Footer Section Ends Here =============*/}
</div>
        )}
    }
```

Comment: Couple of questions: `this.state.count+=1` in map function. Why? In react usually to modify state variable you should call `setState`. And then in `handleChange` function: you set `search_query` and then, if `this.state.count > 0`, you read it? `this.setState` is async and if you  want to read the very latest value of `search_query` you should use `this.setState`'s callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already have everything. It is just a matter of managing things based on your requirement.

You could store the first API call's data in `initData` on the state and use `NCARMap` to store response from server based on the API call's with search string.

You need to handle cases here,

- Initial case when the page loads. `componentDidMount` is anyway making the first api call, so you store that as `this.setState({initData: <response>})`
- When user enters some text (non-empty), you make an API call which either returns data or no data or even error. Hold the response from this in `this.setState({NCARMap: <response>})`. In this case, even if it returns no data, you should show NO DATA. Here you don't want to default to original data because then it would give a wrong impression to user.
- When use clears the search text from the text box, you default to the main state, and for this use just use `this.initData`.

I am just detailing out some steps to give you an idea. Since you already have the code to do most of it, it is just some tweaks and I think you will be able to put together.

Also, please note that class-based components are no longer used actively and function components with hooks are the new paradigm. So, if you have the choice, I suggest using function components, with hooks as it is clearer and recommended from react in general.